# DecorateAllWith in Autofac and Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

On an ASP.NET MVC 5 application I have the following StructureMap configuration:

```
cfg.For(typeof (IRequestHandler<,>)).DecorateAllWith(typeof (MediatorPipeline<,>));
```

http://structuremap.github.io/interception-and-decorators/

I am now using ASP.NET Core ...

Is there an equivalent DecorateAllWith equivalent configuration in Autofac?

Comment: Could you describe what `DecorateAllWith` do ?

Comment: Can you check here http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html

Comment: Hey Miguel would  you mind sharing the autofac setup for meditr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RequestHandler<>))
    .Named("requestHandler", typeof(IRequestHandler,<>));
```

and then:

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(MediatorPipeline<,>), 
     typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), fromKey: "requestHandler");
```

You can check the full documentation [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html).